# The Issue of High Correlations and Maximal Random Structure in Mixed Effects Regression

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-variable

I have two questions and I'd really appreciate your advice on them.

Firstly, I'm looking into the impact of sugar intake on the weight of both children and adults. However, there's an issue because height and group have a very high correlation, given that adults are typically taller than children. Initially, I formulated it as **fm1**, but the correlation between **height** and **Group:height** is strong, with a Variance Inflation Factor higher than 20. When I rewrote it as **fm2**, the Variance Inflation Factor dropped below 10, indicating more stable data. But I'm uncertain if this approach is correct. I'm hoping someone could provide guidance on how to write this code.

```r
fm1 <- lmer(response ~ Group * sugar * (weight + height) + 
            (1 | participants), data = children_adults , REML = TRUE )
```

```r
fm2 <- lmer(response ~ Group * sugar * weight+ sugar * height + 
            (1 | participants), data = children_adults , REML = TRUE )
```

Secondly, should I apply maximal random structure, as suggested by Barr, Levy, Scheepers & Tily (2013)? Would including **height** in the random effects structure impact my investigation on **weight** and **height**?

I'd be really grateful for any insights or suggestions you might have on these issues.

Comment: Some advice about "maximal random structure" by @RobertLong: [Specifing random effects in LMM (LME4) for a "beyond optimal model" in a top down driver approach](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/631213/237901). It's easy to find more relevant CV threads.

Comment: What is the `Group` variable ? Why do you have so many interactions (the fixed effects will be quite tricky to interpret)?. As for implementing the Barr approach, my answer linked by @dipetkov explains that I don't recommend fitting a maximal model. Anyway, let us know about `Group`. Is this binary a binary variable (adult/child) ?

Comment: @dipetkov  Thank you very much for the information!

Comment: @RobertLong Thank you for your reply! 'Group' is indeed a categorical variable (adults v.s children). We want to look at the interaction of 'group:sugar:weight'. Since the 'sugar:height' interaction can affect the results, my supervisor advised me to include it in the model as a control to ensure the accuracy of our results.